# Dimension of a subspace of $Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Here's the question:

> Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $U$,$W$ subspaces of $V$ such that $dimU=k$, $dimW=h$ and $V=U\oplus W$. Consider the following subspacece of $Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V)$:
>   $$\mathbb{D}=\lbrace \phi \in Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V) \enspace | \enspace \phi(U)\subseteq W,\enspace \phi(W)\subseteq U\rbrace$$
>   What is the dimension of this subspace? Give a complement of this subspace.

I know that $Hom_{\mathbb{C}}(V, V)$ is isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ and so has dimension $n^2$, but i have no idea how to identify this specific subspace and assign a basis to find the dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $u_i$ and $w_j$ be arbitrary bases for $U$ and $W$, respectively. They together form a basis for $V$. Translate the condition for $\varphi$ to its matrix representation with respect to this basis.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. Basically the matrix comes as a n×n divided into four "blocks" with h×k elements. Two of this blocks are all zeros because of the given conditions, so the matrix can be written as a sum of 2hk matrices with exactly one element which then is a basis for the given sub space.